# StackOverflow exception in Java while iterating through a hash set

Tags: iteration, stack-overflow, hashset

I am trying to select some objects called elements kept in a hashset. I am iterating over the hashset called elements with foreach like

```
for( Element e: elements).
```

These selected elements are handled in an `ArrayList<Element> el`.

Actually, I haven't any problems a while ago. The method passed from unit tests. Then, suddenly I started to get stackoverflow exception for the method. I debugged. I saw something strange going on there.

I am filling an arraylist and iteration of the elements is finished. Finally, the method must return the arraylist. However, it starts to re-iterate the hashset with setting arraylist empty. I did not understand why this happens. I have been programming for 2 years and this is the first time that I saw this strange thing.

Here is the code if you want to have a look at:

```
public ArrayList<Element> addNextLeftElements(Element firstEl, HashSet<Element> elements, ArrayList<Element> el) {
    for (Element nextEl : elements) {
        if (!nextEl.equals(firstEl)) {
            if (nextEl.overlaps(firstEl, ac.absPrecision)) {
                el.add(nextEl);
            } else {
                for (double dis = 16.0; dis <= 18.1; dis += 0.1) {
                    if (nextEl.transOverlap(firstEl, dis, ac.absPrecision)) {
                        if (!el.contains(firstEl)) {
                            el.add(firstEl);
                        }
                    }
                    for (int displus = 9; displus <= 11; displus++) {
                        if (nextEl.transOverlap(firstEl, dis, ac.absPrecision)) {
                            if (!el.contains(firstEl)) {
                                el.add(firstEl);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return(el);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am facing the same issue in android any suggestions to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This function as it is, is fine.

StackOverFlow exceptions in java are almost always triggered by an infinite loop, so look if one of the functions you call re-calls addNextLeftElements. run the function like this, and simply look at the stack so you know what functions are causing the overflow.

```
 public ArrayList<Element> addNextLeftElements(Element firstEl, HashSet<Element> elements, ArrayList<Element> el) {
try{
for (Element nextEl : elements) {
    if (!nextEl.equals(firstEl)) {
        if (nextEl.overlaps(firstEl, ac.absPrecision)) {
            el.add(nextEl);
        } else {
            for (double dis = 16.0; dis <= 18.1; dis += 0.1) {
                if (nextEl.transOverlap(firstEl, dis, ac.absPrecision)) {
                    if (!el.contains(firstEl)) {
                        el.add(firstEl);
                    }
                }
                for (int displus = 9; displus <= 11; displus++) {
                    if (nextEl.transOverlap(firstEl, dis, ac.absPrecision)) {
                        if (!el.contains(firstEl)) {
                            el.add(firstEl);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return(el);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}